# Asymptotes of a hyperbola

Tags: geometry, asymptotics, conic-sections

[image]

Is this the correct solution something doesnot feel right
[image]

Comment: With $b=-21$, I don't think this is very much an ellipse. Perhaps a hyperbola...

Comment: @Daryl ah yes you are right and I stand corrected, so is the working correct?

Comment: And *definitely* not an eclipse. :-)

Comment: Your write-up is haphazard, but it seems you don't *mean* what you've written. For instance, "$a^2=a$" and "$b^2=b$" are false statements here, but you wind up with the proper values $a=3.16...$ and $b=1.38...$. On the other hand, "$\sqrt{a/b} = \sqrt{1.38.../3.16...}$" is a *true* statement, but an irrelevant one: the gradient you seek should be simply "$b/a$" ... which happens to be the value $0.43...$ you computed. So, your final answer is correct, but your stream-of-consciousness style makes it impossible to judge whether you know what you're doing or just guessed your way through.

Comment: By the way ... If your notes make sense to you, that's *great*. Exactly how your particular thoughts bounce around in your particular brain is no one's concern but your own. However, if you're trying to get people to check your work, or help you find flaws in your reasoning, then you really must make an effort to express those thoughts in a passably-standard way. It's like how twins sometimes develop their own language to communicate with each other; that's terrific --fascinating, really-- but if they ever need driving directions, they're going to want to ask for them in the local dialect.

Comment: @Blue oh sorry I just found this method of taking a screenshot of my Galaxynote 10.1 so was excited to share, but totally agree with you that I indeed need to improve my presentation skills, my tots do bounce in my brain. Will heed your advice, tks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like Blue said, you may better care how to write your thoughts on the paper.

Students like to use the $=\,$ sign for more kinds of things, while in math this has a rather strict meaning. So, instead rather use arrow or colon..
The other thing you messed up is $a$ alias $\sqrt{a^2}$ and $\sqrt{a}$. This latter is not needed now, fortunately.

So, once $a^2$ is found/defined to be $10$, it will stay $10$. Your last 3 lines with more exactness should go like this, for example:

> (Gradients of the) Asymptotes
>
> $a=\pm\sqrt{10}$, $\ b=\pm\sqrt{40/21}$
>
> $\displaystyle\frac{b}{a}=\pm\sqrt{4/21}\simeq 0.43644$